# Find the pair of dictionary keys that have the most common values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to write a function that finds a couple of people with the most common hobbies, that is this couple should have the highest ratio of common hobbies to different hobbies. If multiple pairs have the same best ratio, it doesn't matter which pair is returned and the only exception is when multiple pairs share all of their hobbies, in which case the pair with the most shared hobbies is returned.

```
def find_two_people_with_most_common_hobbies(data: str) -> tuple:
    new_dict = create_dictionary(data) # creates a dictionary in the form {name1: [hobby1, hobby2, ...], name2: [...]}
    value_list = [] # list that stores all hobbies, duplicates included
    for value in new_dict.items():
        for ele in value[1]:
            value_list.append(ele)
    filtered_list = set([x for x in value_list if value_list.count(x) > 1]) # list where hobbies appear more than once, no duplicates
    return tuple([k for k, v in new_dict.items() if set(v).intersection(filtered_list)])
```

So, given the input `"John:running\nJohn:walking\nMary:dancing\nMary:running\nNora:running\nNora:singing\nNora:dancing"`, the output should be `('Mary', 'Nora')`. My code returns `('John', 'Mary', 'Nora')`, because it looks for an intersection between the values in the dictionary and what is in the filtered list. I don't understand how to make it return only shared hobbies.

Comment: If you look at the input yourself and try to solve the problem by hand, how do you decide that the output should be Mary and Nora? How can you perform the same steps in code? What you've coded seems more like a solution to asking "who have hobbies in common with any of the others?". We are to assume `create_dictionary` works correctly, so you should probably share what the example dictionary is that gets assigned to `new_dict` and leave the function call out of the example.

Comment: @Grismar You are right about what my code does. It really looks only for those who have common hobbies in general. And the dictionary looks like this ```{'John': ['running', 'walking'], 'Mary': ['dancing', 'running'], 'Nora': ['running', 'singing', 'dancing' ]}```.

Comment: A couple side-note improvements: 1) Get short-circuiting and greater efficiency by replacing `set(v).intersection(filtered_list)` with `not filtered_list.isdisjoint(v)` (the latter avoids *two* temporary `set`s per call, and can stop processing immediately when it finds the first overlapping element, where intersections must run to completion even if an overlap exists for the first element tested). 2) Write setcomps, don't `set`ify listcomps: `{x for x in value_list if value_list.count(x) > 1}`. Even better would be `{x for x, cnt in collections.Counter(value_list).items() if cnt > 1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this as follows:

- turn the dictionary values into sets
- get all the combinations of people
- compute the [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) (common hobbies) and [symmetric difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference) (different hobbies) of each pair of people
- find the max based on dividing common by different hobbies, using number of common hobbies to split equal values. Note that since the two may have no different hobbies, we use a function to compute the ordering value so that we can catch a ZeroDivisionError.

```py
import itertools

dd = {'John': ['running', 'walking'], 'Mary': ['dancing', 'running'], 'Nora': ['running', 'singing', 'dancing' ]}

ss = { k : set(v) for k, v in dd.items() }
# {'John': {'walking', 'running'}, 'Mary': {'dancing', 'running'}, 'Nora': {'singing', 'running', 'dancing'}}

pp = [t for t in itertools.combinations(dd.keys(), 2)]
# [('John', 'Mary'), ('John', 'Nora'), ('Mary', 'Nora')]

hh = { (p1, p2) : (len(ss[p1] & ss[p2]), len(ss[p1] ^ ss[p2])) for p1, p2 in pp }
# {('John', 'Mary'): (1, 2), ('John', 'Nora'): (1, 3), ('Mary', 'Nora'): (2, 1)}

def most_shared(key):
    try:
        ratio = hh[key][0] / hh[key][1]
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        ratio = float('inf')
    return (ratio, hh[key][0])

res = max(hh, key=most_shared)
# ('Mary', 'Nora')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very informative. To make your code even more meaningful, I suppose one could add ```if dd.keys() is None or len(dd.keys()) < 2: return None```. Then if there are less than two people in the input, the function will simply return None. Well, in my case will, since I have a function.

Comment: @QLimbo yes - I didn't consider the trivial case of a dict with 0 or 1 entry, but what you propose makes sense. Interesting question!

Comment: @QLimbo note you can use just `len(dd) < 2` since a dictionary defaults to its keys when referenced as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "John:running\nJohn:walking\nMary:dancing\nMary:running\nNora:running\nNora:singing\nNora:dancing"
d={}
for v in s.split('\n'):
     k,v=v.split(':')
     if k in d:
          d[k].append(v)
     else:
          d[k]=[v]

for k1,v1 in d.items():
     for k2,v2 in d.items():
          if k1!=k2:
               for v in v1:
                    if v not in v2:
                         break
               else:
                    print(k1,k2)
```